# heap handling in a bison push pure parser

Tags: c, language-design, bison, parser-generator

Is there any way to specify my own allocator/deallocator functions for heap management instead of malloc()/free() for a pure push parser in bison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Most* of Bison's memory allocations can be redirected with macros - in the prologue (between `%{` and `%}`) you can write

```
#define YYMALLOC mymalloc
#define YYFREE myfree
```

and Bison will then call `mymalloc` and `myfree` instead of `malloc` and `free`.  However, it expects whatever functions you provide to have exactly the same type signature as the standard `malloc` and `free`; there is no way to get it to pass extra/different arguments.  And I wouldn't use function-like macros if I were you.  Worse, in my copy (Bison 2.4.1) `yypstate_new` calls `malloc` directly, with no override possible -- this is arguably a bug.

Comment: Yeah I've found it out already, by looking at the generated source. +1 and accepted, a good answer. It doesn't have this bug in 2.4.3.